# Transfer learning with pytorch in python where output is two class

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I am doing a transfer learning using torch.
i want to classify 2 classes.

so, here is the code-:

```
from torchvision import models
net = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)


# this is resnet summary
ResNet(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
  (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer3): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer4): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1000, bias=True)
)
```

when i use `net.fc = nn.Linear(512, 2)` and when i run the code. it throws an error `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1`

#training code

```
net = net.to('cuda')

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
loss_fct = nn.MSELoss()

train_losses = []
val_losses = []
val_accuracy = []
train_acc=[]
for t in range(15):

  net.train()

  X_train = np.array([data_augment(img) for img in X_train])

  epoch_train_loss = 0.
  for i in range(len(X_train) // 64):
    
    X_batch = X_train[i * 64: (i+1) * 64]
    X_batch = torch.tensor(X_batch, dtype=torch.float32).to('cuda')
    X_batch = torch.transpose(X_batch, 1, -1)

    print(X_batch.shape)

    y_batch = y_train[i * 64: (i+1) * 64]
    y_batch = torch.tensor(y_batch, dtype=torch.float32).to('cuda')

    y_pred = net(X_batch)

    loss = loss_fct(y_pred.squeeze(), y_batch)
    epoch_train_loss += loss

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

  train_losses.append(epoch_train_loss / len(X_train))


  net.eval()
  with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred_val = net(X_val)
    loss_val = loss_fct(y_pred_val.squeeze(), y_val)
    val_losses.append(loss_val / len(X_val))
    acc_val = torch.mean(((y_pred_val.squeeze() > 0).int() == y_val).float())

    val_accuracy.append(acc_val)
  print('Train loss: {} Val loss: {} Val Accuracy: {}'.format(epoch_train_loss, loss_val, acc_val))
```

I Want to solve this, i don't know how

when i use `net.fc = nn.Linear(512, 1)`, then it works. but this is not correct if i understand it correctly.

shape and type of my X and y are following:

```
print(type(X_train))
print(type(y_train))
print(type(X_val))
print(type(y_val))


<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
<class 'torch.Tensor'>


print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_val.shape)
print(y_val.shape)

(2600, 315, 270, 3)
(2600,)
torch.Size([500, 3, 270, 315])
torch.Size([500])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you created your final fully connected layer with dim `(512, 2)`, which means for every input `X`, you are expecting a output `y` with dim `(2,)`. This is not the case: your `y_val.shape` evaluates to `(2600,)`, which means the label is a single number.

I think your confusion stems from the fact that you are trying to classify examples into **2** classes. However, every example seems to only have one class, which can be represented by a single number. (e.g. 1 for cat, 0 for dog)

Therefore, the final fully connected layer should have a dim of `(512, 1)`.

In the error you're seeing (reproduced below), `64` is your batch size, and since you're using a FC with `(512, 2)`, the output to each batch prediction is actually `(64, 2)`, instead of `(64)`, which is what it's expecting.

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Comment: means i have to go with `(512,1)`, it will classify 2 classes. am i correct?

Comment: @Coder That's right

Comment: i have one question. basically, I have an Images that has BBOXs.  this data is for Object detection. But i want to use it for classification. my 1st question-: is it ok or not. 2nd-: what should i take care of if i want to do it. Or it is just not possible at all.  please help me with this. thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible. If there's only one bbox per image, you can simply use the class of that bbox as the image label. If there are multiple bbox ed, you'll need to decide how to deal with that. One way is to do multi class classification - have your model output n classes.

Comment: thanks for the Answer. When go with this transfer learning code, accuracy stuck around 50% (not even going up and down). could you tell me what is the problem or what i am missing here? should try another code like this (https://learnopencv.com/image-classification-using-transfer-learning-in-pytorch/)